# How to create a new user account in arangodb?

Tags: arangodb

I am finding trouble to create a new user on arangodb using web UI. In first place I could create a new user,but could not assign a database to the user. Plus, can you also help for a method using arangodb Shell?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arangodb web UI handles users under _system database. If you are not working on root user than first switch to root with _system database access. Find USERS on the navigation panel on left, there you can create and manage new users with database permissions. For now more information on WEB UI user management and management through arangodb shell see link-> https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/operations/administration/user-management/